# Adding entity classes dynamically at runtime

Tags: java, jpa

I have this requirement to add entity classes to the persistence unit at runtime rather than specifying all of them in the persistence.xml. Can someone help me with the same?

I am aware that Hibernate has its own mechanism of doing the same using:

`AnnotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(Class)`, etc - You can also add hibernate config (`*.hbm.xml`) files programmatically.

The requirement is that without restarting the app server, I should be able to keep adding entity classes / their config (mapping) files to the persistence unit dynamically.

But the solution to programmatically add entity classes / configuration files at runtime to the persistence unit should not be specific to a JPA implementation.

Answer (score 33):

JPA doesn't offer this feature yet. Here are three options you can check out :

- [This work around :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744363/363573)
  **1.** Generate a `persistence.xml` on the fly (simple XML file creation) with a new persistence unit.
  **2.** Add persistence file to classpath dynamically (`URLCLassLoader`)
  **3.** Ask `PersistenceProvider` to load new persistence unit (`createEntityManagerFactory`)

*I did implement this workaround. However, it didn't scale well as the number of entities grows (100+). I finally switched to JDBC. Here is a capture of the memory consumption (-75%) before and after the switch from JPA to JDBC.*

[image: Memory consumption reduction by switching from JPA to JDBC]

- [Programmatically loading Entity classes with JPA 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838634/363573)
  This question on SO is similar to yours. An answer reports that it feasible with Spring.
- [JPA 2.0: Adding entity classes to PersistenceUnit *from different jar* automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6380728/363573)
  Good pointers are given here.

**Nota**

If the JPA provider is Hibernate, since Hibernate 4.0, it's possible to pass directly entities to this JPA provider **without declaring them** in the `persistence.xml` file. Hibernate will handle the entities on the fly.

Here is a sample configuration of JPA 2.1 + Hibernate 4.3.7.Final without declaring any entities :

**META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <!-- Database Properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-database" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="login" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

            <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <!-- Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**References**

- [JPA 2.1 Specs : 8.2 Persistence Unit Packaging](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)
- [JPA 2.1 Specs : 8.2.1.6 mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

Comment: Could you please give me information how to configure Hibernate to accept entities without declaring them? It seems that this is not default behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, after trying on other Tomcat it worked like a charm. It is default behaviour and I think was caused because of the gradle-tomcat plugin >.<

Answer (score 7):

I am late to the party, but I think this will save some people some headache. I implemented classpath scanning for pure JPA (no spring etc needed) that integrates with e.g. guice-persist if needed as well.

Here's what you need to do.

First, change the persistence.xml and add your own implementation, like:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="my.persistence.unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>my.custom.package.HibernateDynamicPersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="30" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In order for the Providers to be recognised, you will have to make it discoverable. JPA discovers using the service loading mechanism, so we add:

```
/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

This file has exactly one line:

```
my.custom.package.HibernateDynamicPersistenceProvider
```

Finally add your own provider and base it on the HibernateProvider (I base it on that since I want to use hibernate):

```
public class HibernateDynamicPersistenceProvider extends HibernatePersistenceProvider implements PersistenceProvider {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateDynamicPersistenceProvider.class);

    public static final String CUSTOM_CLASSES = "CUSTOM_CLASSES";

    @Override
    protected EntityManagerFactoryBuilder getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
            PersistenceUnitDescriptor persistenceUnitDescriptor, Map integration, ClassLoader providedClassLoader) {

        if(persistenceUnitDescriptor instanceof ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor) {
            ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor tmp = (ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor) persistenceUnitDescriptor;
            Object object = integration.get("CUSTOM_CLASSES");
        }

        return super.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(persistenceUnitDescriptor, integration, providedClassLoader);
    }

    protected EntityManagerFactoryBuilder getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties, ClassLoader providedClassLoader) {
        log.debug( String.format("Attempting to obtain correct EntityManagerFactoryBuilder for persistenceUnitName : %s", persistenceUnitName ));

        final Map integration = wrap( properties );
        final List<ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor> units;
        try {
            units = PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits( integration );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug( "Unable to locate persistence units", e );
            throw new PersistenceException( "Unable to locate persistence units", e );
        }

        log.debug( String.format("Located and parsed %s persistence units; checking each", units.size() ));

        if ( persistenceUnitName == null && units.size() > 1 ) {
            // no persistence-unit name to look for was given and we found multiple persistence-units
            throw new PersistenceException( "No name provided and multiple persistence units found" );
        }

        for ( ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor persistenceUnit : units ) {
            log.debug( String.format(
                    "Checking persistence-unit [name=%s, explicit-provider=%s] against incoming persistence unit name [%s]",
                    persistenceUnit.getName(),
                    persistenceUnit.getProviderClassName(),
                    persistenceUnitName
            ));

            final boolean matches = persistenceUnitName == null || persistenceUnit.getName().equals( persistenceUnitName );
            if ( !matches ) {
                log.debug( "Excluding from consideration due to name mis-match" );
                continue;
            }

            // See if we (Hibernate) are the persistence provider

            String extractRequestedProviderName = ProviderChecker.extractRequestedProviderName(persistenceUnit, integration);

            if ( ! ProviderChecker.isProvider( persistenceUnit, properties ) && !(this.getClass().getName().equals(extractRequestedProviderName))) {
                log.debug( "Excluding from consideration due to provider mis-match" );
                continue;
            }

            return getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder( persistenceUnit, integration, providedClassLoader );
        }

        log.debug( "Found no matching persistence units" );
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had to overwrite 2 methods, first:

```
protected EntityManagerFactoryBuilder getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
            PersistenceUnitDescriptor persistenceUnitDescriptor, Map integration, ClassLoader providedClassLoader)
```

This is the intercepting method. I added a custom property "CUSTOM_CLASSES" which should really be called "CUSTOM_PACKAGES" which will list all packages that need to be scanned.
At this point I am a bit lazy and I will skip the actual classpath scanning, but you can do it yourself - it's quite straight forward. You can then call

```
tmp.addClasses("class1", "class2");
```

Where the classes are the ones you discovered.

The second method we are overriding is:

```
protected EntityManagerFactoryBuilder getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties, ClassLoader providedClassLoader)
```

This is because the provider we are extending is hardcoded to only allow hibernate classes to create an EMF. Since we have a custom class intercepting the construction, our names don't add up. So I added:

```
String extractRequestedProviderName = ProviderChecker.extractRequestedProviderName(persistenceUnit, integration);

if ( ! ProviderChecker.isProvider( persistenceUnit, properties ) && !(this.getClass().getName().equals(extractRequestedProviderName))) {
        log.debug( "Excluding from consideration due to provider mis-match" );
        continue;
}
```

This extends the normal hibernate check to also include my custom provider to be valid.

Wola, we are done, you now have hibernate enabled classpath scanning with JPA.

Comment: Some questions: Why did you declare CUSTOM_CLASSES constant and never use it? Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: CUSTOM_CLASSES is never used because it is only an examplory config. I don't acutally use it. I use guice to inject my provider with the actual entities I want instead. I use Hibernate 5.1.0.Final You can use the CUSTOM_CLASSES to e.g. pass in package names and then implement your own version of package discovery

Comment: Since Hibernate 4.0 it is possible to pass entities to it without declaring them. Did this feature disappear in 5.1.0.Final?

Comment: I read that as well and it might still be there, however would that also create the table for that entity on the fly? My problem was that I had X libraries contributing entities, and these could change so i could not hardcode them. I could not blindly scan ALL packages, because I don't want all of those entities. I could also not just use them later (i think you are refering to them) because I don't know which ones are available and I must create all tables and relationships fresh on startup (which i believe only happens when creating the EMF), so I needed a way to hook into the creation.

Comment: How do you know which tables to create at startup?

Comment: My persistence strategy is "update" (hmb2dll), which automatically creates the tables and the relationships after analysing all beans that I intend to use. That is why I need the classes to be injected before the EMF is built. This is not out of the box doable with anything (but spring as you pointed out).

Comment: If one is using Hibernate like you anyway, you can much more easily add entities with a MetadataSourcesContributor which can be loaded via service provider:
```java
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataSourcesContributor;
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;

@AutoService(MetadataSourcesContributor.class)
public class MyEntityLoader implements MetadataSourcesContributor {
  @Override
  public void contribute(MetadataSources metadataSources) {
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClassName("...");
  }
}
```