# Dynamic JPA Entity Creation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JavaEE
I have a project which allows the user to create dynamically JPA entities at runtime.
So the user fills a JSF form with entity name and attributes and with this data I want to create automatically an JPA entitiy and finally map this entity in database.
Is this possible with Java EE and JPA? Do I need a service provider like hibernate for this feature?
I searched all over the internet and didn't find any solution or misunderstood the others. Can you please help me and give me some keywords or necessary technologies.
Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding entity classes dynamically at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448950/adding-entity-classes-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: according to the link, it should be possible with hibernate. Can you give me a link to an tutorial or blog?

Comment: Have you seen EclipseLink's dynamic persistence?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic and http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/dynamic_jaxb001.htm